# Cordova ENOENT Error

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I've been testing some cordova admob plugins then this error shows up and I cant add/remove/build or anything now.

> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   'C:/myapp/plugins/com.connectivity.monitor/plugin.xml'

[image]

Does somebody can explain what to do?

Comment: Please don't post your error messages as (cropped) screenshots, but paste the (exact) error in here.

Comment: EDITED. when i cordova build android - Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:/myapp/plugins/com.connectivity.monitor/plugin.xml'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have removed the plugin `com.connectivity.monitor` manually instead of using the Cordova CLI.

Correct way of removing plugins would be `cordova plugin rm com.connectivity.monitor`, which will clean the file system and clean-up all the necessay XML files.

What you could do now to resolve all issues is remove the platform and add it again. Like so:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

After this, make sure that the plugins you need are also installed back again like:

```
cordova plugin add com.google.cordova.admob
```